# Starting Windows Phone Development on Windows 7

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have a requirement to develop a smartphone app ,as part of one of my course modules. 
As I already have some experience with C#  and familiar with the .net Framework, I decided to develop a Windows Phone related app for this. 
However in the Windows phone dev website i see that the requirement to develop for Windows Phone 8 is to have a PC running Windows 8!!! (Rude shock as I only have a laptop running Windows 7 and a upgrade to Win 8 for me is NOT affordable)
My questions are -

A) Is it possible  for me to develop the Application for WP 7 ( which I think IS compatible with my Windows 7 PC )?

Would my app miss out a lot of features available in WP8 and be an obsolete app?

are there any other alternatives you could please suggest?

B)To demo/test on a real device do I need a developer account unlocked phone or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to develop the Application for WP 7

Yes, if you can't upgrade to Windows 8 but want to develop for the WP platform, the WP7 SDK is a good solution. You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570).

Your app should run on every Windows Phone (7 & 8) without trouble.

> Would my app miss out a lot of features available in WP8 and be an
>   obsolete app?

No, it won't be obsolete at all. If the WP7 API set covers your app requirements, it won't be a problem.

The WP8 SDK brings Direct3D, C++, Speech, NFC...

Look at this article for more information about What's new in the Windows Phone 8 SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940(v=vs.105).aspx

> To demo/test on a real device do I need a developer account unlocked
>   phone or is there any workaround?

Yes, you need a developer account to be able to deploy on a device. There is no workaround AFAIK.

At this moment, the annual subscription fee for a Windows Phone Dev Center account has been reduced to **$19 USD** or the equivalent in your local currency (it ends on 8/27/2013).